# Importance of () in Boolean + String for Println

Tags: java, string, boolean, memory-address, println

I was looking for a couple of details as to how Java processes string storage and the println() function, and eventually I created this:

```
String s = "Oh No!";
String t = s;
System.out.println("t == s?" + t == s);
System.out.println(t == s);
```

The console printed:

```
false
true
```

I expected the condition to be true, because the two objects clearly refer to the same memory location. But not only does the println neglect the "t == s?" string; it seems to convert the boolean value to false! Naturally, when I put parentheses around the (t == s) boolean for the first println, the display is as expected:

```
t == s?true
true
```

My question is: Why does the lack of parentheses around the first boolean not only print false, but also causes println to ignore the "t == s?"

This is just out of the ordinary and defies my understanding of Java (which I would say is slightly above AP level as a benchmark).

Comment: you missed the operator precedence of `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations matters, here

```
System.out.println("t == s?" + t == s);
```

is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(("t == s?" + t) == s);
```

you are adding `t` to the `String` before the comparison. You expected

```
System.out.println("t == s?" + (t == s));
```

You could also use formatted io to ensure the order of operations (and eliminate an implicit `StringBuilder`). Like,

```
System.out.printf("t == s?%b%n", t == s);
```

Comment: Wow! That was a really elementary mistake I made there. Thank you!